# SQL DATEDIFF on multiple different start dates

Tags: sql, compare, datediff, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to calculate how many days a batch has been going since it was started using `DATEDIFF`. I'm confident that what I've got would work if there were only one batch, however when I go onto using it for multiple at the same time it obviously won't work the way I want it to.

The issue I have is that there are multiple batches, and each batch has a different start date. So I need the `DATEDIFF` calculation to take into account which particular batch it's looking at when choosing which start date to use. Right now it's just using the earliest date in the table regardless of batch.

```
SELECT 
    T0.[Batch],
    T0.[DateTime],
    DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT TOP 1 T0.[DateTime]
                   FROM t005 T0
                   ORDER BY T0.[DateTime]), T0.[DateTime]) AS [Days],
    MAX(T0.[PG]) AS [PG]
FROM 
    t005 T0
```

The results look like this:

```
Batch         DateTime             Days  PG
3160036  2016-09-30 11:30:52.000    5   11.83
3160036  2016-09-28 08:35:50.000    3   11.85
3160036  2016-09-27 11:27:41.000    2   11.92
3160036  2016-09-26 07:33:27.000    1   12.18
3160036  2016-09-25 12:42:08.000    0   18.16


3160039  2016-09-28 08:28:50.000    3   18.4
3160039  2016-09-27 09:29:42.000    2   53.59
3160039  2016-09-27 09:19:32.000    2   52.73
3160039  2016-09-27 09:12:46.000    2   52.99
3160039  2016-09-27 09:05:52.000    2   53.08
3160039  2016-09-27 08:34:59.000    2   47.17

3160051  2016-10-27 12:56:33.000    32  11.31
3160051  2016-10-27 12:42:58.000    32  11.17
3160051  2016-10-24 06:12:35.000    29  11.18
3160051  2016-10-24 05:57:18.000    29  11.13
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Your current code gives you the  number of days per batch from the start time of that batch to the latest start time overall. What do you want it to do differently ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you look at the sample results, batch 3160039 started on the 27th. It should say 0 days for the first entry there but it says 2 days, as there was another batch (3160036) which started on the 25th. The final entry for batch 3160051 should say 3 days, but it says 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Also a filter was missing + desc sorting...

Have you maybe missed the connection between the batches?

```
CREATE TABLE t005 (
 Batch int
,[DateTime] datetime2
,pg float
)


INSERT INTO t005 values (3160036,  cast('2016-09-30 11:30:52' as datetime2), 11.83)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160036,  cast('2016-09-28 08:35:50' as datetime2), 11.85)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160036,  cast('2016-09-27 11:27:41' as datetime2), 11.92)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160036,  cast('2016-09-26 07:33:27' as datetime2), 12.18)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160036,  cast('2016-09-25 12:42:08' as datetime2), 18.16)

INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-28 08:28:50' as datetime2), 18.4 )
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-27 09:29:42' as datetime2), 53.59)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-27 09:19:32' as datetime2), 52.73)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-27 09:12:46' as datetime2), 52.99)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-27 09:05:52' as datetime2), 53.08)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160039,  cast('2016-09-27 08:34:59' as datetime2), 47.17)

INSERT INTO t005 values (3160051,  cast('2016-10-27 12:56:33' as datetime2), 11.31)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160051,  cast('2016-10-27 12:42:58' as datetime2), 11.17)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160051,  cast('2016-10-24 06:12:35' as datetime2), 11.18)
INSERT INTO t005 values (3160051,  cast('2016-10-24 05:57:18' as datetime2), 11.13)


SELECT 
T0.[Batch],
T0.[DateTime],
(SELECT TOP 1
                T1.[DateTime]
             FROM
                t005 T1
                WHERE T1.Batch = T0.Batch
                  AND T1.[DateTime] < T0.[DateTime]
            ORDER BY T1.[DateTime] DESC) as LastDateTime,
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT TOP 1
                T1.[DateTime]
             FROM
                t005 T1
                WHERE T1.Batch = T0.Batch
                  AND T1.[DateTime] < T0.[DateTime]
            ORDER BY T1.[DateTime] DESC), T0.[DateTime]),0) AS [Days],
T0.[PG]  AS [PG]
FROM t005 as T0
ORDER BY T0.[Batch],
T0.[DateTime]

--drop table t005
```

Output:

```
Batch   |DateTime                    |LastDateTime                 |Days |PG
--------|----------------------------|-----------------------------|-----|----
3160036 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |NULL                         |0    |18.16
3160036 |2016-09-26 07:33:27.0000000 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000  |1    |12.18
3160036 |2016-09-27 11:27:41.0000000 |2016-09-26 07:33:27.0000000  |1    |11.92
3160036 |2016-09-28 08:35:50.0000000 |2016-09-27 11:27:41.0000000  |1    |11.85
3160036 |2016-09-30 11:30:52.0000000 |2016-09-28 08:35:50.0000000  |2    |11.83
3160039 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |NULL                         |0    |47.17
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:05:52.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000  |0    |53.08
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:12:46.0000000 |2016-09-27 09:05:52.0000000  |0    |52.99
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:19:32.0000000 |2016-09-27 09:12:46.0000000  |0    |52.73
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:29:42.0000000 |2016-09-27 09:19:32.0000000  |0    |53.59
3160039 |2016-09-28 08:28:50.0000000 |2016-09-27 09:29:42.0000000  |1    |18.4
3160051 |2016-10-24 05:57:18.0000000 |NULL                         |0    |11.13
3160051 |2016-10-24 06:12:35.0000000 |2016-10-24  05:57:18.0000000 |0    |11.18
3160051 |2016-10-27 12:42:58.0000000 |2016-10-24  06:12:35.0000000 |3    |11.17
3160051 |2016-10-27 12:56:33.0000000 |2016-10-27  12:42:58.0000000 |0    |11.31
```

And Query duration from the first execution of the batch:

```
SELECT 
T0.[Batch],
T0.[DateTime],
(SELECT TOP 1
                T1.[DateTime]
             FROM
                t005 T1
                WHERE T1.Batch = T0.Batch
                  AND T1.[DateTime] < T0.[DateTime]
            ORDER BY T1.[DateTime] ASC) as LastDateTime,
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT TOP 1
                T1.[DateTime]
             FROM
                t005 T1
                WHERE T1.Batch = T0.Batch
                  AND T1.[DateTime] < T0.[DateTime]
            ORDER BY T1.[DateTime] ASC), T0.[DateTime]),0) AS [Days],
T0.[PG]  AS [PG]
FROM t005 as T0
ORDER BY T0.[Batch],
T0.[DateTime]
```

Output:

```
Batch   |DateTime                    |LastDateTime                |Days  |PG
--------|----------------------------|----------------------------|------|-------
3160036 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |NULL                        |0     |18,16
3160036 |2016-09-26 07:33:27.0000000 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |1     |12,18
3160036 |2016-09-27 11:27:41.0000000 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |2     |11,92
3160036 |2016-09-28 08:35:50.0000000 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |3     |11,85
3160036 |2016-09-30 11:30:52.0000000 |2016-09-25 12:42:08.0000000 |5     |11,83
3160039 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |NULL                        |0     |47,17
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:05:52.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |0     |53,08
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:12:46.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |0     |52,99
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:19:32.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |0     |52,73
3160039 |2016-09-27 09:29:42.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |0     |53,59
3160039 |2016-09-28 08:28:50.0000000 |2016-09-27 08:34:59.0000000 |1     |18,4
3160051 |2016-10-24 05:57:18.0000000 |NULL                        |0     |11,13
3160051 |2016-10-24 06:12:35.0000000 |2016-10-24 05:57:18.0000000 |0     |11,18
3160051 |2016-10-27 12:42:58.0000000 |2016-10-24 05:57:18.0000000 |3     |11,17
3160051 |2016-10-27 12:56:33.0000000 |2016-10-24 05:57:18.0000000 |3     |11,31
```

Similar solution using Partition by...

```
SELECT a.* , datediff(day,LastDate,a.[DateTime]) as Diff 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    T0.[Batch],
    T0.[DateTime],
    MIN(T0.[DateTime]) OVER (PARTITION BY T0.[Batch]) as LastDate,
    T0.[PG]  AS [PG]
    FROM t005 as T0
) as a
ORDER BY a.[Batch],
a.[DateTime]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that though and I just get 0 days for every result.

Comment: I changed some of the code and added a test-script, please tell me if this works for you :-)

Comment: Incredible. Thank you very much!